# Чтение JS файла на Python

Tags: javascript, python

Есть программа, которая читает файл и проигрывает файлы которые в нем указаны,
Этот файл playlist.js, который содержит вот такие данные:

```
{
  "audio": [],
  "view": [
    {
      "files":  [
        "video/01.mp4"
     ],
     "type": "video"
    },
    {
      "files":  [
        "video/02.mp4"
     ],
     "type": "video"
    },
    {
      "files":  [
        "video/03.mp4"
     ],
     "type": "video"
    },
    {
      "file": "images/1.jpg",
      "timeout": 10000,
      "type": "image"
    },
    {
      "file": "images/2.jpg",
      "timeout": 10000,
      "type": "image"
    }
  ]
}
```

Вот этот блок содержит видео, которое он проигрывает, это одно видео.

```
    {
      "files":  [
        "video/01.mp4"
     ],
     "type": "video"
    }
```

Вот этот блок содержит запись об изображении, всем и так ясно будет но просто, чтоб вопросы отпали.

```
    {
      "file": "images/1.jpg",
      "timeout": 10000,
      "type": "image"
    },
```

Мне нужно прочесть этот файл, узнать сколько в ней крутится видео/изображений, отредактировать(добавить, удалить) и сохранить в том же виде в формате js. Вопрос первый, какие библиотеки посоветуете, для работы с JS на Python? (Похож на JSON)

Далее, файл playlist.js должен браться из ОС Linux, вопрос второй, какие средства посоветуете, для работы с Linux из под Windows?

P.s пожалуйста, советуйте только русскоязычные источники, а в крайнем случае, можно и на иностранном.

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-json.html

Comment: Структура вашего фала и есть JSON. Поэтому можете использовать любую библиотеку для работы с JSON. Вот примеры:  [https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json]

Comment: Спасибо за источники. JSON библиотекой я уже пользовался, но для записи в файл я написал свое, а чтение, скорее я просто рекурсивную функцию напишу для поиска чисто кол-ва загружаемых (аудио, видео, фото).  Но меня щас более сильнее волнует вопрос об Linux из под Windows, протокол Samba или что-то новенькое есть, по лучше? Хуже? Да и как с Samba поработать? Ноль опыта